# Dynamically Name Datasets in Python Like SAS

Tags: python, sas, naming, sas-macro

I am scraping data from the web for multiple years (2007-2019). I want to output the data in different datasets called df_year, and have the year be the year of the data. In SAS, I could create a macro variable for the year, but not sure how to name datasets dynamically similarly in Python. Thanks!

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you mean by "different datasets"? Are you trying to save the data in multiple files (e.g. CSV)? Or just keep multiple data frames in memory for analysis?

Comment: sorry i mean multiple datasets in memory(i.e. df_2010, df_2011, etc.), I might choose to ultimately save them separately as a CSV or stack, but I want to leave that flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have a notion of macros. The natural way to do what you're looking for is to use a dictionary:

```
df_by_year = {}
df_by_year[2011] = df
df_by_year[2012] = another_df
```

You can then access the data frame of a specific year by `df_by_year[<my_year>]`